# Запуск приветственного окна после установки

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

пишу приложение и использую следующий код для запуска окна приветствия при первом запуске приложения:

объявление переменных

```
private static final String MY_SETTINGS = "my_settings";
private SharedPreferences sp;
String themen;
boolean hasVisited;
boolean sound = true;
```

метод onCreate:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
themen = sp.getString("themen", "Night");
sound = sp.getBoolean("sound", true);

if (!hasVisited) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstStartActivity.class));

    SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
    e.commit();
}
```

При отладке возникли некоторые проблемы. А именно я удаляю приложение, ставлю его на устройство заново и у меня не запускается FirstStartActivity. По логам я понял, что hasVisited = true; Не могу понять почему так происходит
Логи считываю сразу после строки

```
hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
```

и получаю , что `hasVisited = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаление приложения не всегда удаляет файлы приложения из его внутренней папки. Иногда это зависит от прошивки (на `MIUI`, вроде удаляет, а на других - нет). Иногда - от версии ОС (тут не уверен). Также гугл по умолчанию делает бэкап `sharedPreferences` на своих серверах с определённой версии ОС.

Засим это надо учитывать и эмулировать первый запуск не удалением приложения, но очисткой его данных. Возможно также надо запретить бэкап в манифесте чтобы гугл не обновлял вам префы со своих серверов.

Comment: А как это сделать не подскажете?

Comment: @i_burykin, ну, получается ваш код полностью рабочий и тестировать надо просто очищая данные. Ну и отключить autoBackup в манифесте можно.

Comment: я просто не могу найти папку приложения на андроиде, и немного не пойму какие данные надо чистить.

Comment: а про autoBackup я так понимаю в манифесте надо android:allowBackup="true" заменить на false?

Comment: @i_burykin, на нерутованном девайсе папка недоступна. На рутованных и эмуляторах это надо смотреть в `data/data/ПАКЕТ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ`. `Очистка данных` - опция в настройках приложения, доступных через их менеджер на телефоне. Она как раз всё сотрёт в помянутой выше папке. Да, надо `android:allowBackup="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Наверное проблема в том, что вы сначала вызываете Intent, а потом пытаетесь сохранить значение переменной `hasVisited`.

Инициализируйте `SharedPreferences`:

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

private boolean hasVisited;
```

в `onCreate`:

```
mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
```

Получаете значение, по стандарту `false`:

```
hasVisited = mPreferences.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
```

Делаете условие:

```
if (!hasVisited) {
        // Сохраняете значение для переменной hasVisited
        mEditor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true).apply();

        // Вызываете интент
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstStartActivity.class));
    }
```

Comment: Тогда бы у меня каждый раз запускалось приложение, как первый раз. А так, я никак не могу сбросить состояние приложения в первоначальное.

Comment: Студия не предлагает commit на apply заменить? То что я скинул вам, у меня работает прекрасно.

Comment: Нет, не предлагает. У меня дефолтное значение hasVisited получает почему то true